# AVA testing throws

Tags: javascript, testing, ava

I am trying to test by throwing error.

```
 test('throws', t => {
    t.throws(() => { 
    valid(1) }, "Error can't put number");
 });
```

So the valid is function and when I put number I want to throw the error.
Right now it gives me AssertionError: Missing expected exception (err)..

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`t.throws()` asserts that the function you pass it throws an error. You say:

> when I put number I want to throw the error

`t.throws()` doesn't change the behavior of `valid(1)`. If it doesn't already throw, then your test will fail with an `AssertionError`.